# generating Excel through template Excel using XLSTransformer and writing to outputstream but i m not getting the output in the excel file

Tags: java

```
synchronized public void transformq(
        TransformationContext<Map<String, Object>> context, OutputStream o)
        throws ServiceException {
    BufferedInputStream templateInputStream = null;
    if (context != null) {

        try {

            String classPathLocation = !context.getType().getTemplate()
                    .startsWith("/") ? "/"
                    + context.getType().getTemplate() : context.getType()
                    .getTemplate();
            URL templateURL = ClassLoader.class
                    .getResource(classPathLocation);

            if (templateURL == null) {
                throw new ServiceException(getMessage(
                        Messages.MISSING_TEMPLATE, classPathLocation));
            }

            templateInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    templateURL.openStream());
            Workbook workbook = xlsTransformer.transformXLS(
                    templateInputStream, context.getContext());

            workbook.write(o);
            templateInputStream.close();
            o.flush();
            o.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let us know where the problem lies in your code?  Are you getting an exception or simply no output?  Might it be possible that you _are_ getting output but it is in a different place than where you are checking?

Comment: the excel file is getting generated but with some gibrish letters,for testing i wanted to print a single word through template but the file is first of all toggling ,sometime showing 0kb sometime 7 kb ,and in 7 kb it has all encoded letters -i.e some binary data

Comment: How are you creating your `xlsTransformer` ?

Comment: by setting as  a property, its a Spring application